# Nodemailer with gmail get ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: node.js, docker, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I just deploy my nodejs api on Scaleway and when I try to send a mail from it, i get the following error, while it works like a charm locally :

```
command: 'CONN'

code: 'ETIMEDOUT',

at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {

at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)

at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:229:22)

at SMTPConnection._onError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:760:20)

at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)

Error: Connection timeout
```

I'm using the following nodemailer transporter configuration :

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_ADRESS,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
}
});
```

So I try to use the debug option from nodemailer transporter and I figure out that the resolved IP addresses are different.

Locally, the resolved IP address is the following :

```
 DEBUG [pfKLJKySPY] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 142.251.5.108 [cache miss]
```

While in production, the resolved IP is the following :

```
DEBUG [vgPMKJtFZT] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 74.125.140.108 [cache miss]
```

Also, I checked that the container my docker image is running on is not blocking port 456 used by SMTP and no firewall is enabled.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that for the service to work in production, from my server, I had to configure the transport as follows:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
secure: false, 
requireTLS: true,
logger: true,
debug: true,
auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_ADRESS,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
},

});
```

Now i'm able to send mail from gmail through nodemailer from my server !

The `port` has to be configured on `587` and `requireTLS` has to be `true`. Now, the resolved IP address is the following :

```
DEBUG [PHpdgG5NDWI] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 66.102.1.109 [cache miss]
```

And with this address I have no more timeout errors !!!